# Multiple TestFlight builds stuck on "Processing", including already processed ones

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, expo

I just uploaded a new build to the App Store Connect. The build has finished `"Processing"` under the Activity tab, but it's still on `"Processing"` on the TestFlight tab.

The most bizarre thing is that not only the just uploaded Build is `"Processing"` but **ALL OF THEM**, builds that were uploaded and processed long ago.

**Activity Tab**

[image: Activity Tab]

**TestFlight Tab**

[image: TestFlight Tab]

This is the first time I experienced this, does anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you found out what happened or any solution.

Comment: Yes! See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it was only a visual bug on the AppStore Connect. After a long time processing everything went back to normal.